# Tkinter is preventing the video from playing

Tags: python, video, tkinter, easygui

I am new to Python and I am stuck with Tkinter. I have a video running in the background, and I need a label to pop up which contains dynamically changing content. I tried it with tkinter and EasyGUI. The contents are getting printed, but it causes my video to pause. I had to close the pop-up each time, for the video to keep running. I guess the tkinter thread is blocking the video playing thread.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: It will be good if you show some code/example snipped that actually tells the user where you are facing the issue.